# how to fix 'Warning Error loading module file (). Please restore the file or disable the module.' error message?

Tags: drupal

I'm using civicrm 4.5.5 in drupal 6
I enabled tracing to explore another problem and when I removed the defines in the settings.php file that setup the query logging, this error appeared.

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 8):

- Visit your Extensions page @ `civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1`.
- Click *Refresh*.
- If visible, uninstall the extension which is currently not found.
- Worth trying Cleanup Caches too @ civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1